# Is there a way to customize the new Chatter user "Here are some groups you may want to start or join" prompt?

Tags: chatter, customization

We keep having new Chatter users create the default suggested groups "Sales," "Marketing", and "Product" because they are prompted to do so on join.  Can we modify or remove the groups suggested on this step?  Thanks